# Adding an opacity change and a transform in CSS

Tags: css

How do I combine these two animations (translate & buttonFade) so that they both affect the same image ? Both animations work seperatley but not together. Is there a way to combine the two? (I have omitted the -moz- , -o- etc purposefully to make it easier to read, I have tried adding these and it makes no difference)

```
translate {
-webkit-animation: moveLeft 1s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveLeft {
0% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0px)}
100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(100px)}
}




.intro-button{
position:absolute;
top: 350px;
left: 625px;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-animation: buttonFade 3s 1 forwards;
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes buttonFade {
0% {opacity: 0;}
80% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `translate` is not a valid tag name, is it some class? (so it should be `.translate`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list multiple animations by separating them with a comma, as such you can simply call `moveLeft` from your CSS for `.intro-button` and remove your CSS for `translate` (which by the way is not a valid selector).

You'll also want to add a other value for the animation delay, which should be first animation delay + first animation duration (4s)

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/5ZqLQ/)

Change your CSS thusly:

```
@-webkit-keyframes moveLeft {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100px)
    }
}
.intro-button {
    position:absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 625px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: buttonFade 3s 1 forwards, moveLeft 1s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s, 4s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes buttonFade {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

[**You can actually concatenate the animation property further:**](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/5ZqLQ/1/)

`-webkit-animation: buttonFade 3s 2s 1 forwards, moveLeft 1s 4s forwards;`

Removing the need to set animation duration separately The shorthand for`animation` is:

`animation: animation-name animation-duration animation-timing-function animation-delay animation-iteration-count animation-direction animation-fill-mode;`

Comment: thanks so much, i accidentally left the . off of the front of translate, it was a class i had defined in my HTML. this is really helpful !